# sed to insert all necessary bash escapes into a filepath

Tags: bash, sed

I'm looking for a `sed` command to change a human-readable file or directory path (as displayed in a standard terminal or output by `find`) into one that can be used as a bash argument*, e.g. changing the string `My Books/Pride & Prejudice.pdf` into `My\ Books/Pride\ \&\ Prejudice.pdf`.

For now, I'm making do with just inserting a `\` before very `&` or space, but I imagine that there are all sorts of edge cases where this breaks. Hence, I'd like to know whether a more generalized solution exists.

*I realize that the most general version of this question is probably impossible - passing the path as an argument to be processed by arbitrary programs (e.g. further `sed` operations) will potentially require different models of escaping for every program. But I am only looking to use the output directly as paths, e.g. to `cd` there or call `cat` on them.

Comment: `printf '%q\n' 'My Books/Pride & Prejudice.pdf'` will give desired output.. although, depending on your use case, you can use `find+exec` instead of any need for escaping..  for ex: `find -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} +` will automatically apply `cat` for the matching file names... plus, you could always pass `'My Books/Pride & Prejudice.pdf'` (note the quotes) directly as command arguments

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it does the trick! Not entirely sure why this is a comment, though - if you were to adapt it into an answer, I would definitely see it as a complete & satisfactory answer to the question, and I'd be sure to accept it.

Comment: added an answer, I wasn't sure if it would solve your use case

Comment: There is usually no issue passing whatever filename into another utility using `-exec` from `find`.  What is the underlying issue you are trying to solve? This seems to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf '%q\n' 'My Books/Pride & Prejudice.pdf'` will give your desired output. You can use a glob pattern, for example, `printf '%q\n' *` to get the results for multiple files.

Depending on your use case, you can use `find+exec` combination instead of any need for escaping. For example `find -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} +` will pass the matching file names correctly to `cat` command.

Another option, provided your file name doesn't have troublesome characters like single quote and newline, you could manually surround the filename with single quotes and pass it to another command. For example: `ls -l 'My Books/Pride & Prejudice.pdf'`